# Can i serialize any object in the world (in C#)?

Tags: c#, serialization

are there objects or classes i can't serialize ? 
i mean , with Binary serialize that serialize all fields and properties...

Comment: That depends, how much effort are you going to invest? Many classes require a wrapper because there is no serialize/deserialize method explicitly provided.

Comment: It would not make sense to serialize e.g. a `FileStream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic Dictionay is not serializable. You need to implement your own serializer.

Answer (score 2):

Not all classes are marked with the [SerializableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx)

```
[Serializable]
public class Foo
{
  ...
}
```